# python-ARMA predictions converge to zero very soon

Tags: python, time-series, zero

**Trainset's Autocorrelation and Partial Autocorrelation**
[image]

After observing the correlations, I decide to use the `ARMA(3,2)` to build my model, but I find that my predictions converge to zero very soon.

I don't understand why and how to fix it.

```
arma_mod = sm.tsa.ARMA(diff1, (3,2)).fit()
```

**Predictions**
[image]